# GAE Python - How to attach the results of csv.writer to an email?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, email, csv

On GAE Python I am writing a CSV from my datastore and would like to send it by email without storing it in the blobstore. This is intended to run as a CRON job once per day.

The export works fine, however I don't know how to add the CSV to the attachment of the email. Your input would be very much appreciated.

```
class ShopExport(webapp2.RequestHandler):
  def get(self):
    shops = Shop.all().filter('active =', True).order('name')
    self.response.headers[str('Content-Type')] = str('application/csv')
    self.response.headers[str('Content-Disposition')] = str('attachment; filename="shops.csv"')
    writer = unicodecsv.writer(self.response.out, encoding='utf-8')
    writer.writerow(["id", "name", "domain", "category", "deeplink", "region"])
    writer.writerow([shop.keyname, shop.name, shop.url, shop.category, shop.url_aff, region])

    message = mail.EmailMessage(sender="Me <me@gmail.com>",
            subject="Shop Export",
            attachments=[("shops.csv", self.response.out)])
    message.to="Someone <someone@gmail.com>",
    message.html= 'Please find attached the shop export'
    message.send()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to modify this line.

```
message = mail.EmailMessage(sender="Me <me@gmail.com>",
        subject="Shop Export",
        attachments=[("shops.csv", self.response.body)])
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do this

```
import StringIO
...
data = StringIO.StringIO()
writer = unicodecsv.writer(data, encoding='utf-8')
...
message = mail.EmailMessage(sender="Me <me@gmail.com>",
            subject="Shop Export",
            attachments=[("shops.csv", bytes(data.getvalue()))])
```

Comment: +1. The benefit of this over the accepted answer is that this works with deferred tasks etc.