# Emailing csv attachments from Google App Engine without downloading the attachments

Tags: python, google-app-engine, csv, attachment, email-attachments

I found this thread: [GAE Python - How to attach the results of csv.writer to an email?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15449371/gae-python-how-to-attach-the-results-of-csv-writer-to-an-email)

which has been helpful in getting me to be able to attach csv's to an email from Google App Engine. My code is as follows:

```
self.response.headers[str('Content-Type')] = str('text/csv')
self.response.headers[str('Content-Disposition')] = str('attachment; filename="data.csv"')
writer = csv.writer(self.response.out)
[write csv here]

message=mail.EmailMessage(sender='test@example.com',subject='Subject', attachments=[("data.csv",self.response.body)])
message.to=[to email here]
message.html='Message Body'
message.send()
```

The issue is when this code runs, not only is an email sent but a file is also downloaded. Is there a way to prevent the file from being downloaded?

Answer (score 0):

It is downloading because you are writing it to the response output. You should be writing the attachment content to a temporary file/memory and attach that.

Also there is no need to set those headers.

The accepted answer to the SO question you have referenced is incorrect, the other answer is best https://stackoverflow.com/a/15453323/2018227